# How to get a list of entity types the Drupal 9 way?

Tags: entities, 9

I need to get a list of all entity types.

EntityManager is deprecated. In Drupal 9 EntityTypeRepository should be used, though I don't see any reference to its being used.

How would I use this class in a non-static way to obtain a list of all entity types?

Comment: See [EntityTypeRepositoryInterface::getEntityTypeLabels](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityTypeRepositoryInterface.php/function/EntityTypeRepositoryInterface%3A%3AgetEntityTypeLabels/9.0.x). Statically you can use `\Drupal::service('entity_type.repository')->getEntityTypeLabels()`. Non-statically is standard DI, which depends on the type of class you want to use it in.

Comment: Googling `drupal EntityManager is deprecated` gives you a page full of samples how to accomplish this. Please always do some research first, try out what you find and if somethings left unclear provide a reproducible and detailed question of what went wrong. Many thanks

Comment: Yup. Did research, and look through code. EntityTypeManager does the job when you have an entity in mind... not so much when you want all entity types, which is where my research yielded the class I asked about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [EntityManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8.2.x) docs say:

> Deprecated in Drupal 8.0.0 and will be removed before Drupal 9.0.0.
>   **Use [\Drupal::entityTypeManager()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityTypeManager/8.2.x) instead in most cases**. If the needed
>   method is not on \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface, see
>   the deprecated \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager to find the correct
>   interface **or service**.

```
$entity_type_manager = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager');
$entity_definitions = $entity_type_manager->getDefinitions();
// Create a list of entity types.
$entity_types_list = [];
foreach($entity_definitions as $entity_name => $entity_definition) {
  $entity_types_list[$entity_name] = (string) $entity_definition->getLabel();
}
```

Comment: I asked about the other class because EntityTypeManager seems not have a GetDefinitions (plural) method, which is how I eventually found the EnitityTypeRepository class mentioned.

Comment: It does have the `getDefinitions()` plutal method, so you're wrong about that.

Comment: You’re absolutely right. I forgot that there was an interim step where I read that I should instead be using the method getEntityTypeLabels instead, and it was it, not getDefinitions, that forced me to the other class.